Im trying to fetch data from zkteco k40 biometric attendance device from spring boot
I have read somewhere that first we need to be connected to IP port of the device. I got connected through code using websocket.This is my code. when i run this, I got SocketTimedOut Exception...Thats why i increased time of READ_TIMEOUT, Still this problem is occuring? What I did wrong ? What should I do to connect and fetch data from BIOMETRIC Device?
    public String getAttendanceData() {
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
        Socket socket = null;
        DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;

        try {
            // Establish a socket connection to the device
            socket = new Socket();
            socket.connect(new InetSocketAddress(DEVICE_IP, DEVICE_PORT), CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
            socket.setSoTimeout(READ_TIMEOUT); // Set socket read timeout

            System.out.println("Connection established to device at " + DEVICE_IP + ":" + DEVICE_PORT);

            // Send authentication request with the username and password
            String authCommand = "AUTH:" + USERNAME + ":" + PASSWORD;
            dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            dataOutputStream.write(authCommand.getBytes());
            System.out.println("Sent authentication command to device: " + authCommand);

            // Wait briefly before continuing, to ensure the device has time to process
            Thread.sleep(1000);

            // Read the response from the device
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line).append("\n");
            }

            System.out.println("Received response from device.");
        } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
            System.err.println("Connection timed out: " + e.getMessage());
            return "Error: Connection timed out while fetching attendance data.";
        } catch (SocketException e) {
            System.err.println("Connection reset: " + e.getMessage());
            return "Error: Connection reset. The device might have closed the connection unexpectedly.";
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("I/O error while communicating with the device: " + e.getMessage());
            return "Error fetching attendance data: " + e.getMessage();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (reader != null) reader.close();
                if (dataOutputStream != null) dataOutputStream.close();
                if (socket != null && !socket.isClosed()) socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.err.println("Error closing resources: " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        return response.toString();
    }
}

Im trying to fetch attendance data from that device

Have you tried it with an alternative client first?
